# jqgrid dynamic columns - show data on footer

Tags: jquery, grid, footer

I have a problem...

I have a jqgrid that show some data, but the columns are dynamic. The grid run well. This is my code:

```
...
var colMode = [];
...
var columnas = data.d;
$.each(columnas, function (index, col) {
...
colMode.push({ name: col.ColumnName, index: col.ColumnName, width: '100%', align: 'right' });
...
$("#gridCalendario").jqGrid({
                datatype: function (pdata) { getData(pdata); },
                height: 'auto',
                colModel: colMode,
....
```

The problems is that I want to show data on footer, but I can not do this, because I don't know how  to indicate the name of the columns dynamic. The following code, show how I'm trying to do it:

```
    function sumarValores() {

        var sumaHa = 0;

        var columnNames = jQuery("#gridCalendario").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');

        $('#gridCalendario').jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Items: 'TOTAL:' });

        for (var z = 0; z < columnNames.length; z++) {
            var colN = columnNames[z];
            $('#gridCalendario').jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { colN: parseFloat(sumaHa).toFixed(2) });
        }
    }
```

Can Somebody  help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved the problem  with the following function:

```
    function sumarValores() {

        var sumaHa = 0;

        var columnNames = jQuery("#gridCalendario").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colNames');

        $('#gridCalendario').jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Items: 'TOTAL CUENTA:' });

        for (var z = 0; z < columnNames.length; z++) {
            var colN = columnNames[z];

            var obj = '[{"' + colN + '": "' + parseFloat(sumaHa).toFixed(2) + '"}]';

            var colFoot = JSON.parse(obj);

            $('#gridCalendario').jqGrid('footerData', 'set', colFoot[0]);

        }

    }
```